# Enumerate users for each day

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase

I'm new to Android Development. I have an **`Activity`** with a **`ListView`** where appears selected items from an user and where he save them to **`firebase`**.

In this Activity I want to enumerate each user who save items to **`Firebase`** something like a tracking number and display in another activity number of user, prices of selected items and number of items selected by user.

I have prices of selected items and number of items selected by user but just displayed in a Toast, because I don't know how to send all of them to another activity in **`ListView`**.

```
 int totalPrice = 0;
 for(VanzatorProduse v : Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse())
 {
       int vPrice = Integer.parseInt(v.getPret());
       totalPrice = totalPrice + vPrice;
 }

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected products : " + listaProdusePreview.getAdapter().getCount() +"\n"+"Total sum : " + totalPrice , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But for next day enumeration needs to start from 0.

I have looked for many tutorials but I have no idea from where to start. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

To send data to another **`Activity`**, you can do :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in your **`NewActivity`** :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```

Edit : As for resetting the enumeration to 0, you can use the **`AlarmManager`.**
for example :

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PedingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Then create a **`BroadcastReceiver`** :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
        //reset enumeration to 0
    }
}
```

Comment: and how can i give for each user a number when he is saving items to firebase ?

Answer (score 0):

**Passing all Data to next `Activity`**
Take an **`ArrayList`** of VanzatorProduse type and send **`ArrayList`** data to next **`Activity`** using **`Parcelable`** and **`serializable`** objects using Bundle, **`SharedPreferences`** or saving in file(Multiple options)

**For next day enumeration needs to start from 0**
For this you can use **`BroadcastReceiver`** Listener to clear **`ArrayList`** and can start from 0

Answer (score 0):

Here below example shows you how to pass data onItemClick for particular position.

```
ListView listview = getListView();


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("position", arraylist.get(position));
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });
```

Save your enumeration value in **Firebase**  database and retrieve from firebase.

Happy coding!!